# connecting to the internet while nat is disabled

Tags: nat, static-ip

I have four PCs, and i want to use one of them as a web server, but i still want to surf the internet from the four PCs at the same time.

in Egypt we have an ISP called "tedata" which offer three static IPs packages to choose from, the following from their support forum:

---

1- Option Pack 1: subnet mask [255.255.255.252] /30
It provides 2 IPs, one for DSL router, one for PC.

2- Option Pack 2: subnet mask [255.255.255.248] /29
It provides 6 IPs, one for DSL router, 5 for PCs.

3- Option Pack 3: subnet mask [255.255.255.240] /28
It provides 14 IPs, one for DSL router, 13 for PCs.

---

i want to subscribe to "Option Pack 1" since i want only one static IP, but their instruction about configuring it say that i must disable NAT.

my question is how can my other PCs reach the internet if i disabled NAT?

Comment: I don't get why you should disable NAT to configure this. If they state that one IP is for a router NAT must be possible as this is what a router does. Can you link to those instructions?

Comment: here is the link of the pdf file that illustrate the setup process:
http://www.tedata.net/eg/Multimedia/pdf/Routers%20Configuration/3com/How%20to%20setup%203com%20Router%20%5BStatic%20Configuration%5D.pdf

Comment: This seems very strange to me. A router is the bridge between WAN and LAN. If I get it right they tell you to enter your static IP as LAN IP. If you dial in with PPPoE you should have your static IP assigned as WAN IP. Then you should be able to configure your LAN to your likings. Including DHCP-Server, Freely choosen IP and NAT. Maybe you have to configure your static IP manually, but this should definitely not happen in the LAN options.